# Event listener not being triggered

Tags: javascript, event-listener, phoenix-live-view

I'm trying to dispatch a custom event when an XMLHTTPRequest completes, and have a listener  capture it and initiate the next action. However, the event listener is not being triggered as expected. I tested the same event listener by adding it to `window` and it works, but not when the event listener is added in a hook as shown below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Uploaders.Cloudinary_Direct = function(entries, onViewError) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    let {
      url,
      fields
    } = entry.meta

    Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, val]) => formData.append(key, val))
    formData.append("file", entry.file)
    formData.append("upload_preset", "avatar_upload");
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    onViewError(() => xhr.abort())
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 204) {
        entry.progress(100)
      } else {
        entry.error()
      }
    }
    xhr.onerror = () => entry.error()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

        console.log("public_id")
        let event = new CustomEvent("cloudinary_external_upload", {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          detail: {
            public_id: get_public_id(xhr)
          }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event); // also tried window.dispatchEvent.. in vain
      }
    }
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        let percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100)
        if (percent < 100) {
          entry.progress(percent)
        } else {
          entry.progress(100)
        }
      }
    })

    xhr.open("POST", url, true)
    xhr.send(formData)
  })
}

Hooks.ExternalUpload = {
  mounted() { // <-- This ensures the listener is add only after the component is mounted.
    this.el.addEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', e => {
      console.log("cloudinary_upload") // <-- This is never printed.

      this.pushEvent("external_upload", {
        id: this.el.id,
        public_id: e.originalEvent.detail.public_id
      });
    });
  }
}

let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {
  hooks: Hooks,
  uploaders: Uploaders
})
```

EDIT: The debug inspector shows the event listener is properly added to the HTML element.
[image: event listener added to element]

Comment: Looks like `this.el` is not referring to an html object. Did you try to print it to see what it is.

Comment: Did you referenced a Hook with `ExternalUpload` in one of your HTML element? Like `<input phx-hook="ExternalUpload" />`, because this seems to be how the Hooks will add the HTML elements to reference them later.

Comment: @KeitelDOG. Thanks for your response. I added a screenshot above to show the HTML element and event listener are shown in the inspector.

Comment: Then it might be on `this.dispatchEvent(event);`. First, your `dispatchEvent(event)` is called outside the condition where you create the `event`. I don't know about Phoenix Live View, but `dispatchEvent(event)` should be called from an element. I don't know what this is referring too in you case, because you use `xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {`, then the `this` normally refers to the `function()`, and not to `Uploaders.Cloudinary_Direct` function, which is not an element. You could place `const that = this;` on top just to see. If I had a Snippet online, I'm sure I would see the issue.

Comment: Just tried `const that = this;` but unfortunately it didn't make any difference. As I mentioned in the post, `window.addEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', e=> ...` does get triggered as expected which makes me think `this.dispatchEvent(..)` is working. It's just not hitting the listener in the hook for some reason.

Comment: I also tried to add `this.pushEventTo(document.getElementById("upload-form-container"),"external_upload", {public_id: e.detail.public_id});` to `window.addEventListener` and got this error `Uncaught TypeError: exports.pushEventTo is not a function`. I wonder what exports refers to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257042/discussion-between-keiteldog-and-jason-o).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple of issues causing your event listener not to trigger as expected:
Here's how you can refactor your code to address these issues:

```
    Hooks.ExternalUpload = {
  mounted() {
    const el = this.el; // Capture the correct scope
    
    const cloudinaryUploadHandler = function(e) {
      console.log("cloudinary_upload");
      this.pushEvent("external_upload", { id: el.id, public_id: e.detail.public_id });
    };

    this.el.addEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', cloudinaryUploadHandler.bind(this)); // Bind the correct scope

    // Clean up event listener when the hook is destroyed
    this.handleEvent("disconnect", () => {
      this.el.removeEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', cloudinaryUploadHandler);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Since he used ES6 function in `this.el.addEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', e => { })`, he didn't lose the scope of `this` object. ES6 function doesn't have `this` object. Also the OP updated the Question to show that the event has been successfully added to the `div` element. Now it's just a matter of dispatching this event using the div element reference.

Comment: @KeitelDOG I think you mean "arrow function". ES6 functions include both traditional and arrow functions.

Comment: @Barmar yes, sorry, I meant arrow function that was introduced first in ES6 syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, looking at your custom event...

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      
      console.log("public_id")

      let event = new CustomEvent("cloudinary_external_upload", {bubbles: true,  cancelable: true, 

        detail: {

            public_id: get_public_id(xhr)
        } 
  });

    this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Why are you dispatching outside of the readystate condition? I would place it inside like so...

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      
  console.log("public_id")

  let event = new CustomEvent("cloudinary_external_upload", {bubbles: true,  cancelable: true, 

    detail: {

        public_id: get_public_id(xhr)
    } 

this.dispatchEvent(event);

  });
```

If left outside you're dispatching when the custom event doesn't even exist yet.

Excuse the mess... FF is really playing up tonight... or maybe SO has a bug.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax. You have a function call inside an object literal.

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation in the OP. Now you can see that it's inside `if` block.

Comment: Yes, I realize my boo-boo… his tabbing confused me. How to delete…

Comment: Click on the Delete link below the answer.

Comment: All I'm seeing is... Share, Edit, Flag

Comment: That's strange. If it's your own answer you should see Share Edit Delete Flag

Answer (score 0):

The event listener had to be added to window instead of this.el.

```
Hooks.ExternalUpload = {
  mounted(){ 
    // window instead of this.el
    window.addEventListener('cloudinary_external_upload', e => {

     this.pushEvent("external_upload", {id: this.el.id, public_id: e.detail.public_id});
    });
  }
}
```